# Dependency Injection in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm building Symfony 3.3 application. I have a helper in a Console folder:

```
abstract class AbstractHelper implements HelperInterface
{
    protected $httpClient;

    public function __construct(HttpInterface $httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }
}
```

And I have implementation of **HttpInterface** named **HttpGuzzle** into Service folder. How could I help Symfony to figure out I want to inject **HttpGuzzle** into **AbstractHelper** constructor? I tried to add these line to services.yml but it doesn't work:

```
AppBundle\Command\AbstractHelper:
    arguments:
        $httpClient: AppBundle\Service\HttpGuzzle
```

If i run the tests it throws an error:

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Command\AbstractHelper::__construct(), 
0 passed in ~/Projects/app/tests/AppBundle/Console/HelperTest.php 
on line 17 and exactly 1 expected
```

With this:

```
helper:
    class: AppBundle\Command\AbstractHelper:
    arguments: [AppBundle\Service\HttpGuzzle]
```

I get an error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "helper".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `services.yml` You have to define the **HttpGuzzle** service itself, like this:

```
httpguzzle:
    class: AppBundle\Service\HttpGuzzle
```

Then you can use pass it to the helper like this:

```
helper:
    class: AppBundle\Command\AbstractHelper
    arguments: ["@httpguzzle"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just handled this issue. But seems it doesn't work when I trying to get service from the tests. `static::createClient()->getContainer()->get('helper');` I get the same error about non-existent service.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Can you post it? The fact that you're trying to instance an abstract class may have something to do with it.